# How to keep application authorized (Twitter OAuth)

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, authorize

So, i'm using twitter OAuth API and trying to display tweets from my home timeline and it succeed

But, every time i want to access tweets from my home timeline, i need to authorize my application, if i just reload the page where i put the tweets, then the tweet will be empty

I wan't it like dabr, so user login using twitter, and whatever the user does, user doesn't need to authorize the app again

Any solution?

Comment: You should just save the OAuth instance into `$_SESSION`.

Comment: By the way, I produce my very useful library, **UltimateOAuth**. If you can read Japanese a little, feel free to take a look at GitHub. https://github.com/Certainist/UltimateOAuth You can also make OAuth authorization as if using **xAuth** one. I named this **para-xAuth Authorization**.

Comment: @CertaiN: what do you mean by OAuth instance (sorry, i'm new to twitter OAuth API), also i don't know japanese language

Comment: What library are you using? `twitteroauth.php`?

Comment: yeah, Abaraham's twitter oauth library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you will be helped by setting a TwitterOAuth instance itself into the session.

```
<?php

// Make sure to load library before starting session
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

session_start();

if (isset(
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'],
    $_GET['oauth_verifier']
)) {

    // TwitterOAuth instance, with two new parameters we got in twitter_login.php  
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET', $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

    // Let's request the access token  
    $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);

    // Save TwitterOAuth instance in a session var
    $_SESSION['twitteroauth'] = $twitteroauth;

    // Reset parameters
    unset($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['twitteroauth'])) {

    $twitteroauth = $_SESSION['twitteroauth'];

} else {

    die('Error');

}


// You can request here using $twitteroauth.
```

Comment: did you mean `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` on the first code?

Comment: Umm... If you mean them gotten after calling `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token`, that's true.

Comment: Yes, that is `$token_credentials = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);` quoted from GitHub

Comment: `$access_token` means `$token_credentials['oauth_token']`, and `$access_token_secret` means `$token_credentials['oauth_token_secret']`.

Comment: People frequently use these names for the sake of telling `access_token` from `request_token`.

Comment: i don't know where to use that code, would you please help me? here's my code: http://pastebin.com/0cdsCH35

Comment: Updated. Take a look at this.